# System.IO.DeleteFile throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I'm trying to delete a file using System.IO.DeleteFile and it's inexplicably throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException. I realize this has been asked many times. I've look through all the questions I can find and none of the answers seem to apply. I happen to be using FAKE but the issue seems more generic.

Here's my entire build.fsx:

```
// include Fake lib
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open System.IO

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    DeleteFile "./Newtonsoft.Json.dll" |> ignore
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

And I get this exception running `Fsi.exe build.fsx`:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path './Newtonsoft.Json.dll' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.Delete()
   at FSI_0001.clo@6.Invoke(Unit _arg1) in c:\Apache24\htdocs\IS4C\pos\is4c-nf\scale-drivers\drivers\NewMagellan\build2.fsx:line 7
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 483
```

If I run `del Newtonsoft.Json.dll` from the same command prompt, the file deletes just fine.

It doesn't appear to be a permissions issue. The file is not read-only or hidden. And unless my actual build file is somehow opening an extra handle to the file I don't see how it would be open in another process.

Those appear to be the three standard answers to this issue. Are there any additional answers?

Comment: The file may be held by a running process. And judging by the fact that this only happens inside FAKE script, I'd say that the script itself may be that process.

Comment: Considering that [the FAKE source code references Newtonsoft.Json a lot](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=newtonsoft), I'd say it's very likely that FAKE itself is using that DLL.

Comment: Just be aware that I didn't manage to reproduce your problem: similar `build.fsx` runs on my box without any problems deleting `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` so **it has nothing to do with `FAKE` library dependencies**. I'd recommend you to uncover and post here your runtime current directory by showing `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` from the script as your two relative paths to dlls do not coincide with what I'd expect from regular `FAKE` nuget installation.

Comment: You could iterate the loaded assemblies in the appdomains held by your process to see who if anyone has loaded the dll. There are tools that allows you to find which processes has files opened (Process Explorer by sys internals are one). One thing that tend to work in windows when you can't delete a file due to the file being opened is that renaming tend to work. Perhaps you can do something with that.

Comment: FAKE was installed via paket rather than nuget. I actually *built* the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the current working directory using FAKE. There's another copy of it in ./packages/FAKE/Tools/Newtonsoft.Json.dll that presumably gets used the first time I run my build. I guess on subsequent runs FAKE is using the dll I'm trying to [re-]build rather than the one that's installed with the package.